# How can i use javafx webview?

Tags: java

I have tried to use javafx viewer but it seems that import javafx.scene.web.WebView; is not recognized, even when I add manually the jars, the ide recognized it but in the build it doesn't work.

I am using maven, how can i add dependencies to make a simple webviewer?
What about the module-info.java?

Comment: WebView is in the module javafx-web. You must include it as a maven dependency, and when starting the module must be on the module path.

Comment: “…in the build it doesn't work.”  Edit your question and include the full text of the compile error you’re getting.  ‘It doesn’t work’ is generally not enough information for others to provide assistance.